spring boot kotlin - jwt problem - csrf seems to be enabled even though I disabled it
I work on a Spring Boot Kotlin project and have problems with my JWT implementation. In the debugger I get this error: Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/auth/register which indicates that CSRF is not disabled, I dont get why though. Besides that I always get a 401 back even though I try to access routes that should work. This is my SecurityConfig.kt:
class SecurityConfig(private val jwtUtil: JwtUtil) {

    @Bean
    fun securityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        val publicUrls = arrayOf("/auth/register")
    
        return http
            .csrf { csrf ->
                csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers(RequestMatcher { request: HttpServletRequest ->
                    publicUrls.any { url -> request.servletPath.equals(url) }
                })
            }
            .authorizeHttpRequests { authz ->
                authz.requestMatchers(RequestMatcher { request: HttpServletRequest ->
                    publicUrls.any { url -> request.servletPath.equals(url) }
                }).permitAll()
                authz.anyRequest().authenticated()
            }
            .addFilterBefore(JWTAuthorizationFilter(jwtUtil, publicUrls), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
            .sessionManagement { it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) }
            .build()
    }
    
}

And this here is my JWTAuthorizationFilter.kt:
class JWTAuthorizationFilter(private val jwtUtil: JwtUtil, private val publicUrls: Array<String>) : BasicAuthenticationFilter(null) {

    override fun doFilterInternal(request: HttpServletRequest, response: HttpServletResponse, chain: FilterChain) {
        val requestUrl = request.servletPath
        if (publicUrls.contains(requestUrl)) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response)
            return
        }
    
        val token = request.getHeader("Authorization")?.removePrefix("Bearer ")
    
        if (token == null || !jwtUtil.validateToken(token)) {
            response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED
            return
        }
    
        chain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
}

And as a sidenote, antMatchers for some reason doesnt work for me.
Thank you already for your help.
I already tried to disable csrf in multiple ways but nothing worked.
